# Does AWS Athena partition projection support more than one `storage.location.template`?

Tags: amazon-athena, amazon-cloudtrail, aws-control-tower, aws-landing-zone

AWS ControlTower managed CloutTrail created account-trail-logs which used `/org id/AWSLogs/…` log path in S3 bucket, until Landing Zone 3.0 update which replaced it with organization-trail logs whose new log path is `/org id/AWSLogs/org id/…`.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/controltower/latest/userguide/2022-all.html

This poses challenge with the AWS Athena partition projection. The original DDL is as follows:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE cloudtrail_logs_partition_projected( 
    eventVersion STRING,
    userIdentity STRUCT< 
        type: STRING, 
        principalId: STRING, 
        arn: STRING, 
        accountId: STRING, 
        invokedBy: STRING, 
        accessKeyId: STRING, 
        userName: STRING, 
        sessionContext: STRUCT< 
            attributes: STRUCT< mfaAuthenticated: STRING, creationDate: STRING>, 
            sessionIssuer: STRUCT< type: STRING, principalId: STRING, arn: STRING, accountId: STRING, userName: STRING>>>,
    eventTime STRING,
    eventSource STRING,
    eventName STRING,
    awsRegion STRING,
    sourceIpAddress STRING,
    userAgent STRING, 
    errorCode STRING, 
    errorMessage STRING, 
    requestParameters STRING, 
    responseElements STRING, 
    additionalEventData STRING, 
    requestId STRING, 
    eventId STRING, 
    readOnly STRING, 
    resources ARRAY<STRUCT< arn: STRING, accountId: STRING, type: STRING>>,
    eventType STRING, 
    apiVersion STRING, 
    recipientAccountId STRING, 
    serviceEventDetails STRING, 
    sharedEventID STRING, 
    vpcEndpointId STRING )
PARTITIONED BY ( `accountid` string, `region` string, `date_created` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.amazon.emr.hive.serde.CloudTrailSerde'
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'com.amazon.emr.cloudtrail.CloudTrailInputFormat'
OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION 's3://<s3-bucket>/<org-id>/AWSLogs/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'projection.enabled'='true', 
  'projection.accountid.type'='injected',
  'projection.region.type'='enum', 
  'projection.region.values'='eu-north-1,ap-south-1,eu-west-3,eu-west-2,eu-west-1,ap-northeast-3,ap-northeast-2,ap-northeast-1,sa-east-1,ca-central-1,ap-southeast-1,ap-southeast-2,eu-central-1,us-east-1,us-east-2,us-west-1,us-west-2', 
  'projection.date_created.format'='yyyy/MM/dd', 
  'projection.date_created.interval'='1', 
  'projection.date_created.interval.unit'='DAYS', 
  'projection.date_created.range'='2021/01/01,NOW', 
  'projection.date_created.type'='date', 
  'storage.location.template'='s3://<s3-bucket-name>/<org-id>/AWSLogs/${accountid}/CloudTrail/${region}/${date_created}')
```

Since the `LOCATION` and `storage.location.template` are different for the older and newer s3 objects (i.e., logs from CloudTrail), what is the best solution to query the cloudtrail logs, old and new? I prefer a single Athena Table for both older and newer logs, but I am not sure if multiple `LOCATIONS` are supported.